# How do you have a graph in two different rankdirs?

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to createa mind map. Currently I have a `rankdir = LR`.

So it looks like,

Node ----------> Node1

I have been trying for,

Node2 <------------- Node -----------> Node1

but failed.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this with `dot` unless you're willing to define edges the *wrong* way (from Node2 --> Node) and add `dir=back` to the attributes of of the edge. This may be ok with a simple one-shot graph, but difficult to automate.

For a mindmap, I'd use a different layout algorithm, like `neato` for example.